# Writing a C++ program that can merge files from the command line in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, merge

I have written a C++ program that is supposed to open two text files (**prog2a.dat** and **prog2b.dat**) and write the contents of a specified range of lines to an output file (**outfile.dat**). I wrote a program that based on the example we were given (to take lines `5-15` from the first file and lines `4-12` of the second file and merge them into the output file) works perfectly. However, after asking my professor for some clarification on another part of the assignment, I found out I have not done this correctly. I have the code written so that it will always output the range of lines I mentioned earlier, but the program is actually supposed to allow the user to merge the files from the command line using whatever range they want by typing in the following command:

```
prog2 in1 5-15 in2 4-12 outfile
```

But I'm not sure how to tweak my current program to allow this to be done.

Here is the code that I have written, keep in mind that this works properly for the way it is written, but not how it is supposed to work for the purposes of the command line (hopefully that makes sense):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Create output file
    std::ofstream outFile("outfile.dat", ios::out);

    // Open input file 1, if can't be opened, exit
    ifstream in1;
    in1.open("prog2a.dat");
    std::string line;
    int count = 1;
    if (!in1) {
        cerr << "Open Failure" << endl;
        exit(1);
    } // end if
    else {
        while (std::getline(in1, line)) {
            if (count >= 5 && count <= 15) {
                outFile << line << "\n"; /*writes the contents of
                lines 5-15 to outfile.dat*/
            }
            ++count;
        } // end while
    } // end else
    in1.close(); // close in1 (prog2a.dat)
    outFile << "\n"; // add a blank line after the output from prog2a.dat
    count = 1; // reset the line count to 1 before opening next file.

    // Open input file 2, if can't be opened, exit
    ifstream in2;
    in2.open("prog2b.dat");
    if (!in2) {
        cerr << "Open Failure" << endl;
        exit(1);
    } // end if
    else {
        while (std::getline(in2, line)) {
            if (count >= 4 && count <= 12) {
                outFile << line << "\n"; /*writes the contents of the
                lines 4-12 to outfile*/
            }
            ++count;
        } // end while
    } // end else
    in2.close(); // close in2 (prog2b.dat)
} // end main
```

Is there any simple way to make this work as I described using the command line? Also, I am supposed to break this up into three files, a header file, the program file, and a test file (the test file contains `main()` and should close the 3 open files and display any error messages), but I'm getting really confused as to what should go in the header file. I know the header file should contain class definitions and constructors, but don't really know how to make that work for this specific program? I'm extremely new to this so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This program really compile? `(class prog2 { int main()..})`?

Comment: Yes, and produced the correct output in the output file.

Comment: You cannot have the main() inside a class, this is not java. Your program does not compile, just copy/pasted it and tried with g++.

Comment: Ah ok, must've added the class after I ran it. I'll get that fixed, thanks for pointing it out. Like I said, I'm really new at this and am learning as I go.

Comment: You should declare `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and use its arguments. You don't need any own `*.h` header for a single source program (but of course you need to `#include` several standard headers)

Comment: I know a .h header file isn't actually necessary for this type of program, but the directions of the assignment say that I have to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that line numbers and file names are hardcoded in your main function. As mentioned in the comments, you need to handle main function arguments. Also your code contains duplication that can easily be moved to separate function (reading input files and copying required strings to output). I've removed some duplication by moving the related code to separate functions. You still need to check for errors: take a look at `//TODO` comments in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


bool lineNumbersFromString(const std::string& aString, int& startPos, int& endPos)
{
    std::size_t pos = aString.find('-');

    if (pos < 0 || pos >= aString.length())
    {
        return false;
    }


    std::string start = aString.substr(0, pos);
    std::string end = aString.substr(pos + 1, aString.length()-1);

    if (start.length() == 0 || end.length() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    startPos = atoi(start.c_str());
    endPos = atoi(end.c_str());

    return true;

}

bool copyLinesToOutFile(std::string& inputFileName, int startLine, int endLine, std::ofstream& outFileStream)
{
    ifstream inputFileStream;
    inputFileStream.open(inputFileName.c_str());

    if (!inputFileStream)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open file: " << inputFileName << endl;
        return false;  
    } 

    int lineCount = 0;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inputFileStream, line))
    {
        if (lineCount >= startLine && lineCount <= endLine)
        {
            outFileStream << line << "\n";
        }
        ++lineCount;
    }
    inputFileStream.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 6)
    {
        //Invalid number of arguments
        //TODO: report error
        return -1;
    }

    std::string firstFileName = argv[1];
    std::string firstFileRange = argv[2];
    std::string secondFileName = argv[3];
    std::string secondFileRange = argv[4];
    std::string outFileName = argv[5];

    int firstStartPos = 0;
    int firstEndPos = 0;

    bool ok = false;

    ok = lineNumbersFromString(firstFileRange, firstStartPos, firstEndPos);
    //TODO: check error

    // Create output file
    std::ofstream outFile(outFileName.c_str(), ios::out);

    ok = copyLinesToOutFile(firstFileName, firstStartPos, firstEndPos, outFile);
    //TODO: check error

    int secondStartPos = 0;
    int secondEndPos = 0;
    ok = lineNumbersFromString(secondFileRange, secondStartPos, secondEndPos);
    //TODO: check error

    ok = copyLinesToOutFile(secondFileName, secondStartPos, secondEndPos, outFile);
    //TODO: check error

    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Hope this helps. Splitting it to separate files should not be much of an issue.

Comment: BTW the code doesn't check that line numbers are valid for input files and that input files are long enough. You'll probably want to add this logic as well.